# What's the difference between `dovecot-lda` and `deliver` in master.cf of postfix?

Tags: postfix

In `master.cf` of postfix, after `dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe`,
I always add :

```
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

Then I can receive email to my virtual mail address.
But somebody said shoud use `deliver` instead of `dovecot-lda` as below:

```
flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

My server is centos 7,virtual mail address stored in Mariadb 5.5.
Both `deliver` and `dovecot-lda` can be found in `/usr/libexec/dovecot`. And I can send and receive mail with both setting.
Which one should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's the same thing! deliever is a symlink to dovecot-lda

```
[root@mail2 dovecot]# ls -la deliver
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11  2 okt  2017 deliver -> dovecot-lda*
```

If you check

- man deliver
- man deovecot-lda
  they both show the same manual page

Comment: Why did dovecot put deliver here?to make people confused?

Comment: For ease of configuration. If you choose to install a different component to replace dovecot, it will create the `deliver` symlink. This way it is not necessary to change the configuration of postfix.

Comment: Additionally, it is quite common with linux utilities to have a single binary that is linked to. The binary determines by the name by which it is called which functionality is used. If you run `ls -l /bin` you'll find a lot of symlinks to related binaries.